# django-push-notifications in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-push-notifications

I'm trying to use `django-push-notifications` library in my Django REST backend project. I have used Firebase Cloud Messaging. Here is the implementation;

settings.py

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
    "FCM_API_KEY": "private key from FCM app"
}
```

views.py

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=email, username=username)

if created:
    GCMDevice.objects.create(registration_id="token", cloud_message_type="FCM", user=user)
```

models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Action)
def create_new_action(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        devices = GCMDevice.objects.filter(Q(user=instance.admin)|Q(user__in=instance.users.all()))
        msg = "New action is created in %s" % instance.name
        devices.send_message(msg)
```

My question is what should `registration_id` be while I'm creating the GCMDevice object for each registered user?

Answer (score 0):

`registration_id` come from your frontend

actually you must have an api that get user(frontend) fcm token or get it(fcm token) in user registration or login api's

Answer (score 0):

The `registration_id` is the same as the `endpoint` key from the client-side `PushSubscription` object.  which looks like this:

```
{
    "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/...",
    "expirationTime": null,
    "keys": {
        "p256dh": "...",
        "auth": "..."
    }
}
```